# ¿Como poner la fecha de días anteriores a la actual usando el comando Date en Unix?

Tags: nginx, terminal, unix

Estoy tratando de crear un archivo con nombre de la fecha de hace 4 días. Sé cómo poner la fecha de hoy, pero no sé cómo poner una fecha anterior a hoy. ¿Alguien sabe?

Convertir el siguiente ejemplo para que diga la fecha de hace 4 días:

Gracias por su ayuda

```
dt=`date +%d-%b-%Y`
touch ./respaldo-$dt.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo conseguí:

```
dt=`date -d "-4 days" +%d-%b-%Y`
touch ./respaldo-$dt.zip
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo esto responde a la pregunta. A ti puede parecerte obvio lo que hace, pero para otros que más adelante podrían tener un problema similar, no.